# JPA(Hibernate) - find nearest 10 objects by longitude / latitude

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

How can I query nearest 10 objects ( Distributors in my case) by longitude / latitude.

Every Distributor have longitude / latitude coordinates. I'm using and Spring Data for simple queries, but as I know, there is no option to use Spring data for this kind of query.

Comment: You can use a custom query to fetch the data as per your requirement, Something like this 
 `@Query("SELECT t.title FROM Todo t where t.id = :id") 
 
String findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);`

Comment: This is not useful. I don't need to find distributor by id.

Comment: How about using stored procedure, if the query is complex and you don't want to handle it via specifying custom parameters, Here is a guide that can help you with it. [Calling stored procedure via spring data](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585358/1126526). You will have to add `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses to the query shown in the answer to get the nearest/farthest 10.

Answer (score -1):

If you can do this in the underlying database, you can add a *Named Native Query* to your Entity class, and use the Entity Manager to execute that query.

For example, my `GeoUnit` class has a Geofencing Native Query, taking two parameters for latitude and longitude:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GeoUnit.geofencing", query = "SELECT * FROM GeoUnit g WHERE " +
    "g.shape.STContains(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' || :longitude" +
    " || ' ' || :latitude || ')', 4326)", resultClass = GeoUnit.class)
public class GeoUnit {
  // ...
}
```

Invoking it:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("GeoUnit.geofencing").setParameter("longitude", lon)
    .setParameter("latitude", lat).getResultList();
```

To have your Entity class containing a geospatial data type in Java (it does not necessarily have to), you could e.g. use Hibernate Spatial: http://www.hibernatespatial.org/